# Is there a way to search for terms with punctuation?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, search

I recently wanted to search for "underscore underscore try" and "underscore underscore finally" but the search feature removes the leading "underscore underscore".  This sort of thing is also a problem if you're searching for things that start with "." Is there any way around this?

-EDIT-
This is also a bit of a problem "__try" and "__finally" eats the underscores in the preview but not in the posted question.

Answer (score 1):

This works now but you must put the term in quotes

> "__finally"